# Committing to git and local folder structure

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

I have a project written in Laravel 4. Everything goes to "master" branch in Bitbucket. I'm migrating my app to Laravel 5 and I'd like to keep both versions in my git repo as separate branches.
My local folder structure looks like this:

```
Project - this is my main git repo folder
    ˪name - Laravel 4 code is here, all in git already, on "master" branch
    ˪name5 - Laravel 5 code is here, not in git yet. Should go to a separate branch
```

How do I go about achieving that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to commit all the current changes on `name` to your master branch. Then create an empty branch in the same folder, let's say `develop`, and move `name5` to `name`.

Finally, commit/push your changes to this new branch.

1. Commit/push you current changes (easy to do)
2. Create an empty branch in the same folder: `git checkout --orphan develop`
3. Clear the working directory: git rm --cached -r .
4. Move the content of `name5` to `name` (without removing name/.git/ folder)
5. Commit/push your changes to the new branch.